# Cannot use object of type WP_Term as array

Tags: php, wordpress

Given these categories:

```
_Hello
_1979
```

I am running this:

```
    $option = " ";
    $categories = get_categories( array( 'hide_empty'  => 0 ) ); 
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
      // Since string indexing is zero-based, we want to check if
      // the first char is an underscore and
      // the second character is a digit
      if( $category[0] === '_' && ctype_digit( $category[1] ) ) {
        // chop off the leading underscore
        $category = substr( $category, 1 );
      } else {
        $option .= '<option>'.$category->name.'</option>';
      }
    }
    return $option;
```

But it returns:

> Cannot use object of type WP_Term as array

Basically first I check if a `Category` has an `underscore` and if so I check if it starts with a `string` or a `number`. And if it's a `string`, then I output the `<option>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$categories`   contain a collection of objects (object of type WP_Term)  and not an array so, assuming the object contain an attribute  name   you shuold access  as

```
  $category->name
```

and

```
if( $category->name[0] === '_' && ctype_digit( $category->name[1] ) )
```

Comment: You won't believe it, but I was actually going to answer myself as I have resolved it doing exactly that, thanks a lot tho, will accept it.

Comment: sometime happen  .. better two solution than nothings .

Answer (score 1):

`$category` is an object, not a string, so you can't check the first character of it. You also can't take a substring of it as per the next line.

What you probably should be looking at instead is `$category->name` for all those instances where you try to reference `$category` as a string.

```
if( $category->name[0] === '_' && ctype_digit( $category->name[1] ) ) {
    // chop off the leading underscore
    $category->name = substr( $category->name, 1 );
```

Comment: You won't believe it, but I was actually going to answer myself as I have resolved it doing exactly that, thanks a lot tho

Comment: That's great. Sometimes it works like that -- asking a question can actually help prompt you to think of the answer for yourself.  :-)

Comment: `substr` should work per your original code, but with `$category->name` instead of `$category`. `str_replace` will also work, but will remove *all* underscores, rather than just a leading one. Either way, use `$category->name`, not `$category` or `$category->name[0]` like in your comment.